# Probability of density function is greater than one

Tags: probability, density-function

I'm working on a probability function : $$\frac{x}{2}-2$$ and am trying to find the probability of a value falling between 4.5 and 7.5. I set up the equation as $$\int^{7.5}_{4.5}\frac{x}{2}-2\ dx$$ and get $$\bigg [\frac{x^2}{4} - 2x\bigg]^{7.5}_{4.5} = 3$$  which is confusing because I thought a probability couldn't be greater than 1. Would 3 be valid or am I not understanding a concept?

Comment: What is the range of your pdf integration..

Comment: what is the range of your random variable? It is surely not supported on the entire real line...

Comment: I believe the range is $$4<=x<=infinity$$ because the question states that we know the minimum density is 0.

Comment: the range $[a,b]$ can't be unbounded as the integral of the range $[a,b]$ needs to be $1$. If the lower bound is $a=4$, then try to find the upper bound $b$ such that the integral is $1$.

Comment: Oh, I think I am confused on how to find the bounds then as well. I thought it would be where $$f(x) = 0)$$ and on. I'm supposed to use the integral to find the bounds?

Comment: @user251257 The range $[a, b]$ can't be unbounded for this particular function; in general, it can. (Consider the normal distribution, for instance)

Comment: Would anyone have a link to how to find bounds for a pdf?

Comment: @DylanSp: have I claimed that the support of any random variable needs to be bounded?

Comment: @user3344393: Read your assignment again. Usually the range is given...

Comment: The question before finding the probability is finding the range: "Find the values of x1 and x2 that make this a valid distribution function relative to x if we know the minimum density of the function is zero. "

Comment: Then why don't you attack the questions in their right order?

Comment: I thought I did and the range was 4<=x<=infinity, but I just found out I had solved that wrong, which is why I was asking how to find range now

Comment: @user3344393 Either edit this question or create a new question to directly ask about finding the valid range; we can then answer that. Once you have that, if you're still having issues with this problem, you can create a followup question.

Comment: "which is why I was asking how to find range now" This is not what you were (are) asking, which is why the aim of the question was (is) difficult to get.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:[a,b]\to[0,\infty)$ be a probability (density) function. You know that the probability of having a value falling in the interval $[c,d]\subset [a,b]$ is given by $$\int_c^d f(x)\ dx. $$

Also, $[a,b]$ is the set of all possible values. Therefore, the integral of the probability function over all the domain is the probability of having any possible value, which has to be $1$. With this, we conclude that $$\int_a^b f(x)\ dx = 1.$$

In your case, $f(x) = \frac{x}{2}-2$. So if $[a,b]$ is the domain of $f$, it's necessary that $$\int_a^b \frac{x}{2}-2\ dx = 1.$$

If you are getting a value bigger than $1$, it's certain that you are integrating beyond the domain.

**PS:** if you already know $a$ then it's possible to find the bound $b$. Just substitute the value of $a$ on the integral above and solve the equation for $b$.